# how to extract object .net

Tags: c#, oop, object

I have a function that returns this object:

```
 var result = AjaxUserToPlacePaging();

 //this is the object
 object[] objcs = new object[1];

 objcs[0] = new
 {
     countHereNow = countHereNow.ToString(),
     countWillBeHere = countWillBeHere.ToString(),
     countWasHere = countWasHere.ToString()
 };
```

How can I extract the information from the object?

for example

```
 int count  = result[0].countHereNow;
```

the resun i nned the function to be object is because 
i using jquery
and with the jquery it takes the object and converting it into json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend making a custom class, and storing that, instead of just storing an anonymous type into an "object" directly.

```
objcs[0] = new MyClass
{
    countHereNow = countHereNow.ToString(),
    countWillBeHere = countWillBeHere.ToString(),
    countWasHere = countWasHere.ToString()
};
```

That will allow you to cast it back, when you retrieve:

```
MyClass myClass = result[0] as MyClass;
if (myClass != null)
{
    int count = myClass.countHereNow;
}
```

There are tricks you can do to work with anonymous types, but in most cases, they just make the code less maintainable.

Comment: `if (myClass != null)`. This is C#.

Comment: if you impleicity declare the array, you wounld't have to create a type, as per answer below.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Thanks - fixed.  @Jaimal Chohan:  That works fine, provided you don't want to use this outside of your local scope (ie: return from a method).  It's less than obvious, though, IMO.

Comment: If you know what you're doing and using caching wisely, anonymous types combined with reflection can be very powerful, as shown by the ASP.NET MVC framework.

Comment: @DrJokepu: I completely agree, and use them regularly, but they can also (easily) lead to maintanence nightmares.  I still feel that creating your own custom class is often the best practice, rather than letting the compiler create a class for you.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx):

```
string countHereNow = string.Empty;
Type objType = result[0].GetType();
PropertyInfo prop = objType.GetPropertyInfo("countHereNow");
countHereNow = prop.GetValue(result[0], null) as string ?? string.Empty;
```

Typically I think returning an anonymous type is a bad idea, but maybe you have a reason for it. Otherwise, I would create a custom class and just return an array of that class type.

Comment: this return 
 CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: What exactly are you returning? Your code doesn't show that... you'll need to make sure "result" is of type object[] for this to work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection (or something that uses reflection) to get the contents of your anonymous object outside the function where you create it. Maybe you should create a class and return instances of that instead?

Answer (score 0):

You're currently declaring the array as an object array

```
object[] objcs = new object[1];
```

Declare it as a implicitly typed (var) array

```
var objcs = new [];
```

That way the objects you actually adding to the array won't be of SystemObject type but will be implicitly typed

Comment: Sure it would.  By impliclty declaring the type, you don;t have to explicity create a class to access the properties.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would assume you can't return that from a function though.

Comment: +1: This is the simplest option IF you're only using this within the same method.

Comment: Thats very true, I had a case of RTFQ :(